# How to change dataype of calculated column number to text in power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a power bi report with live connection to the SSAS cube. I have a numeric column which I wanted to convert to text using DAX, since its a live-conection i cannot change this on power bi end. is there a way ?

Comment: Try checking out this forum post for text to string in Dax: [https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-function-for-converting-a-number-into-a-string/td-p/50731](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-function-for-converting-a-number-into-a-string/td-p/50731)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format function in dax,

For example you can add a new column as the following example:

New_Column = FORMAT(Table1[NumericColumn];"General Number")

Get this example from the source in [Pre-Defined Numeric Formats for the FORMAT Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/dax/pre-defined-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function)

Hope this can help you!